# how to disable lamp shape behind object with glass material? (when rendering)

Tags: rendering

how to disable lamp shape behind object with glass material when rendering?
Its not appear when rendering camera in this order -> camera-lamp-glass object
but it is appear in this order -> camera-glass-lamp
[image]

Comment: I already try it, but no luck... I even uncheck everything but still the rectangle shape of light still appear when i render it behind the glass material object

Comment: What are the odds, I was just now trying to solve this same exact problem with my scene. Unfortunately I came to no conclusion. could not make it invisible through a glass shader.

Comment: Please upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can take a look.

Comment: It solved, in ligth selected, in object tab(property window) in cycles setting, uncheck transmission,,
It will make light shape (rectangle shape) disappear in rendering when the light behind the glass object (mesh with glass shader)

I've tried it before but no luck, but this time is success, I think I do mistake before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if I have understood the question properly. However, have your tried selecting "Transparent" in the Material section for the object you don't want to be seen in the rendered view?

Comment: It solved, in ligth selected, in object tab(property window) in cycles setting, uncheck transmission,,
It will make light shape (rectangle shape) disappear in rendering when the light behind the glass object (mesh with glass shader)

I've tried it before but no luck, but this time is success, I think I do mistake before.